# Xcode iPhone - Create a Table (NOT a Tableview) within a view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, html-table

Is it possible to create a normal data table (HTML equivalent would be ".." as I would like to display some structured information within my scroll view along with text etc and also be able to style each row etc. I would require 3 cols by numerous rows basically.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually create the cells using `UILabel`s. I'd suggest making a new class `LabelTable` that subclasses `UIView`. It could take column and row counts as arguments to the `init` selector. At init just set the `frame`s of the `UILabel`s to `CGRectZero`, then set all the text on all the cells, then in `layoutSubviews` actually take care of sizing the cells and aligning them correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for the rely, i thought this might be the case, the abvoe explanation of doign a seperate class might confusing me, but the way around it that I was contemplating was creating labels as the data (as mentioned) then using rectangles to encase them with the correct background colour, to be the actual cell, just thought there might be an easier way. Thanks

Comment: How I got around this to create my table view in HTML then style it with inline css etc then creating UIWebView I loaded it locally within the webview with interaction turned off.